Finding a SF story where a woman just touches a man's cheek
Towards the end of the novel Cetaganda by Lois McMaster Bujold, there is a very intimate scene, at the same time quite chaste, and loaded with a lot of sexual tension, involving two characters between which not only marriage but even any sexual intercourse is just unthinkable, for a lot of reasons.

She (...) raised one fine hand to touch his left cheek. It was the first time they had touched.

This scene reminded me of a very similar one, also involving two characters between which not only marriage but any sexual intercourse was unthinkable, and also where the woman just touched the man's cheek (not sure which one). I don't remember where I read it, but I am positive it is SF, because the reasons that separated them had a SF origin. But whether it is in a novel, a novella or a novelette, I have no idea. I just don't think a short story is enough to build the tension between these two characters, but who knows ? Nor do I remember when I read it, but it was many years before I read Cetaganda, shortly after its publication in 1996.
Does this ring a bell to anyone ? Thank you.

Gladia Delmarre and Elijah Baley again? She took off her glove and touched his cheek before he left.

I recall a similar scene from old Superman comics. Reproduction on the planet Krypton was conducted artificially. Superman's Kryptonian parents, Jor-el and Lara, shared one such touch - their only physical contact - after sending the infant Superman on his way to Earth, and as Krypton was destroyed.

@StanleyWebb Thank you, but it was a written text, (in fact, a novel, but I did not remember the length), but not comics. Interesting, though, that the same scene would have appeared at least once more.

From one of your previous questions I know that you have read The Naked Sun by Isaac Asimov, and so I will propose the same book as an answer here.
At the conclusion of the novel, Gladia takes off one of her gloves and lightly touches Elijah Baley's cheek:

She stopped three feet away, then slowly, as though in a trance, she
began to remove the glove on her right hand.
Baley started a restraining gesture. ‘Don’t be foolish Gladia,’
‘I’m not afraid,’ said Gladia.
Her hand was bare. It trembled as she extended it.
And so did Baley’s as he took her hand in his. They remained  so for
one moment, her hand a shy thing, frightened as it rested in  his. He
opened his hand and hers escaped, darted suddenly and  without warning
towards his face until her fingertips rested  feather-light upon his
cheek for the barest moment.

There was indeed sexual tension between the two, but no possibility of acting upon it. Baley was married, and Gladia had been raised almost devoid of human contact, and so suffered a phobia of being near other human beings.
In the next book in the series, The Robots of Dawn, we learn how important this moment was to her:

"Our last meeting on Solaria — I hope you remember it, Elijah — taught
me something. I touched you! I removed my glove, one that was similar
to the glove I am wearing now, and I touched your cheek. The contact
did not last long. I don’t know what it meant to you—no, don’t tell
me, it’s not important—but it meant a great deal to me."
She looked up, meeting his eyes defiantly. “It meant everything to me.
It changed my life."


Yes ! I did not connect the "touching the cheek" with the "light portrait" but indeed, both relate Gladia Delmarre and Elijah Baley. Same book, two different memories !

I don't think anybody ever said that Asimov wrote romance well, but that scene at the end of The Naked Sun was actually pretty good.

I totally agree with you !
